# seq and seq_along, best of both worlds?

Tags: r

If I want to number all elements in two vectors, vector 1 gets all odd bumbers and vector 2 gets all even numbers, I can do this assuming the vectors are of length 10.

```
seq(1, 10, by=2)
[1] 1 3 5 7 9

seq(2, 11, by=2)
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

but if my vector has only one element I will run into problems:

```
 seq(2)
[1] 1 2
```

so I use:

```
seq_along(2)
[1] 1
```

BUT I cant use `by=` in `seq_long()`. How do i get the reliability of `seq_along` with the functionality of `seq()`?

---

This example might clear things.

Imagine I ahve two lists:

```
list1 <- list(4)
list2 <- list(4)
```

`list1` must get even names along the element of the list.
`list2` must get odd names along the element of the list.

I dont know how long the list elements will be.

```
seq_along(list1[[1]]) # this will know to only give one name but I cant make it even

seq(list2[[1]]) # this know to give 1 name
#and
seq(2, list1[[1]], by=2) # this gives me even but too nay names
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  You aren't passing a `vector` in any of these statements.

Comment: The example has actually confused me more than the original question.  Are you aware that `list1 <- list(4)` only contains a single value?  Perhaps you meant to use something like `list1 <- integer(4)`?  And lists don't get names, so I'm now confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a function that adds a 'by' argument to seq_along:

```
seq_along_by = function(x, by=1L, from = 1L) (seq_along(x) - 1L) * by + from
```

and some test cases

```
> seq_along_by(integer(), 2L)
integer(0)
> seq_along_by(1, 2L)
[1] 1
> seq_along_by(1:4, 2L)
[1] 1 3 5 7
> seq_along_by(1:4, 2.2)
[1] 1.0 3.2 5.4 7.6
> seq_along_by(1:4, -2.2)
[1]  1.0 -1.2 -3.4 -5.6
```

Answer (score 1):

one way i just found is:

```
  y <- seq_along(1:20)
  y[y %% 2 == 0 ]
  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
  y[ !y %% 2 == 0 ]
  [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

But this will only work when my vectors are even. Must be able to do better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you really want is a to get the 'seq' function to return only odd or oven numbers 1..max or 2..max, respectively.  You would write that like so:

```
seq(1, max, by=2) # Odd numbers
seq(2, max, by=2) # Even numbers
```

Where `max` is the top number in your series.  The only time this will break is if `max` is less than 2.

**Update 1**: There seems to be a bit of discussion about what the OP is requesting.  If we assume there are two existing vectors to be numbered, we can obtain the total number of vector items using `max <- length(c(vector1, vector2))` to obtain the maximum number being used.  Then, the indices would be assigned like so:

```
vector1 <- seq(1, max, by=2)
vector2 <- seq(2, max, by=2)
```

And this will work for any set EXCEPT when one vector does not have any elements at all.

**Update 2**: There is one final approach, which you can take if your vectors do not represent all values between 1 and `max`.  This is how it would work:

```
vector1 <- seq(1, length(vector1) * 2, by=2)
vector2 <- seq(1, length(vector2) * 2, by=2)
```

This independently assigns the values of vector1 and vector2 according to their own lengths.

Comment: if there is one element in the vector that gets even names.  This does not work `seq(2, 1, by=2)`

Comment: The `max` in the answer is only set once for both vectors, so length=1 vectors will still work, because `max = 2` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to `split` odd and even elements in a vector, you can do just that:

```
x <- 1:19
split(x,x%%2)
$`0`
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18

$`1`
 [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

To extract the odd and even numbered elements, use `lapply` on this list using `seq_along` to enumerate the element numbers:

```
x <- rep(c("odd","even"),times=4)
lapply(split(seq_along(x),seq_along(x)%%2),function(y) "["(x,y))
$`0`
[1] "even" "even" "even" "even"

$`1`
[1] "odd" "odd" "odd" "odd"
```

This can of course be made into a function:

```
split_oe <- function(x) lapply(split(seq_along(x),seq_along(x)%%2),function(y) "["(x,y))
split_oe(1:10)
$`0`
[1]  2  4  6  8 10

$`1`
[1] 1 3 5 7 9

> split_oe(2)
$`1`
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding another answer to address what may be your intent of the question rather than the question as you've stated it.

Let's assume you have a couple arrays, `A1` and `A2`, with values, and you want to link an index to those values, so you can say `index[n]` and get a corresponding value from `A1[n/2 + 1]` if `n` is odd and `A2[n/2]` if `n` is even.

We would build a new vector, `index`, like so:

```
# Sample arrays
A1 <- sample(LETTERS, 5, rep=TRUE)
A2 <- sample(LETTERS, 5, rep=TRUE)

n_Max <- length(c(A1,A2))
index <- integer(n_Max)
index[seq(1,n_Max,by=2)] <- A1
index[seq(2,n_Max,by=2)] <- A2
```

Now, `index[n]` returns `A1` values when `n` is odd, and returns `A2` values when `n` is even.  This breaks if `length(A2)` is not equal to or one less than `length(A1)`.